# #nltk download problem, [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host while downloading nltk library

Tags: nltk

I am encountering an issue while attempting to download NLTK packages. Each time I initiate the download process, an error message appears in front of the NLTK downloader. Unfortunately, I am uncertain about the exact source of the problem.

Initially, I encountered a "WinError 10061" error, which led me to suspect a potential problem with the server or proxy settings. In an attempt to address this, I switched to a different server named "mangod." However, this change did not resolve the issue, and I am now encountering a "WinError 10054" error.

My objective is to successfully download all the packages that are available within NLTK. I am carrying out this process within a Jupyter Notebook environment. I am seeking assistance to determine the underlying cause of these errors and to achieve the successful download of NLTK packages as intended.